# Run concurrent jobs on a single gitlab runner machine

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Our gitlab runner managers are running on EC2 machines and we have docker+machine as Executor to launch EC2 spot machines.

We need to enable to run concurrent jobs to improve our performance, etc. What we intend to implement, is run multiple jobs on each spot machine. For achieving it, I reproduce our case in a simple construction with one registered runner with docker-machine executor:

```
concurrent = 2
check_interval = 0
listen_address = "0.0.0.0:9252"

[[runners]]
  name = "shared-runner"
  limit = 1
  request_concurrency = 2
  ...
 [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 0
    IdleTime = 300
    MaxBuilds = 10
    MachineDriver = "amazonec2"
    MachineName = "gitlabrunner-%s"
    MachineOptions = [
    "amazonec2-request-spot-instance",
    ...
    ]
```

Then I start 2 simple jobs at the same time and I expect that on a spot machine 2 jobs running at the same time. But what I get is one job is running and second job remains pending and they are executed sequentially. I don't want intentionally launch second machine. I see the `request_concurrency` has not effect here.

Can anyone here give me some hints? Thanks

**Versions:** 
Gitlab: 14.3.2 
Runner: 14.3.2

Comment: You set `limit` to 1 which means only 1 job can be handled at a time by that runner.

Comment: yes, if would set to 2, it launches new machine for second job, but i wanted both jobs run on a same machine. BTW, according the feedback from gitlab which I received, it is not possible run more jobs on a single VM with docker+machine executor.

Comment: Yes, that's the intended behavior of the executor.